# values are returned but not seeing outputs

Tags: c

I'm new to programming and trying to learn C here. Below is my toy program.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int cmp(int a, int b)
{
    if (a > b)
    {
        return a;
    }
    else
    {
        return b;
    }
}

int main()
{
    cmp(10, 20);
    printf("testing...");

    return 0;
}
```

My question is, in the main function, cmp() function is called, and the value 10 and 20 is passed into cmp() function.

In this case, b is larger than a, so it goes to the else branch. b should be returned, which is 20 in this case. Why am I not seeing any outputs on the terminal?

Comment: Cmp function call inside the main should return an integer so you dont assign this to any value, so you need to make something like `int result = cmp(10,20);` and then print the result, You can use this line to print `printf("%d", result );`

Comment: That makes sense! Simply return b won't show me the output, right?

Comment: *"Why am I not seeing any outputs on the terminal?"* So you don't see `testing...` either? In that case add `\n`  to print newline.

Comment: I can see `testing...` from the output, but not the value of `b`, which I'm expecting to see. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 1):

Your function will return an integer value; however, in your "main" function you call your "cmp" function but don't do anything with it.  The "printf" function is only instructed to print out "testing..." currently.  Here is one possible suggestion for checking the output of your function in the "main" function.

```
int main()
{
    printf("Testing the value of cmp(10, 10) is %d\n", cmp(10, 20));

    return 0;
}
```

Hope that helps.

Regards.

Comment: Answer is correct, but probably better to show assignment of the return to a variable to demonstrate how to make the return usable in more than `printf()`. (see comment below main question)

Comment: Yup.  I won't disagree.  I guess I was just trying to provide a minimalist answer.  Thanks.

Comment: No worries. Good rule of thumb to remember when answering -- you step into the rote of the teacher, so you always want to be one of the good teachers they remember. Never hurts to add another example below your current one that shows use of the return directly. Up to you.